# Make PHP Script count MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage that is listing the results of each given day of a month using the following code.

```
  $day_events = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."'";
  $events_result = mysql_query($day_events);
  while($event_row=mysql_fetch_array($events_result)) {
  $calendar.= "<span>".$event_row['event']."</span>";
  }
```

How can I edit this to list the number of events that are found in the...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."'
```

...query?

Comment: "How can I edit this to list the number of events" - instead of the current output or in addition to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$day_events = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."'";
print mysql_result(mysql_query($day_events),0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_events WHERE day ...
```

BTW you could simply use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) from your previous query.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo mysql_num_rows($evenets_result);
```

Looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$events_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($day_events));
```